# Google Earth Plugin using Google.Load()

Tags: extjs, google-earth-plugin, sencha-architect

There is probably a simple answer to my question although any help will be appreciated.

I use ExtJs with my GE plugin. To get the plugin working I need to include the following in my main HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MDS</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" id="GoogleEarth"></script>
    <script src="/static/googleearth/Ext.ux.GEarthPanel-1.3.js" id="GoogleEarth">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("earth", "1");
        google.load("maps", "2.xx");
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Now when I want to remove the following code and try to run it as javascript alone the page seems to keep on loading.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("earth", "1");
        google.load("maps", "2.xx");
    </script>
```

Even if I remove the code and paste it inside it's own .js file the problem persist.

For example use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/GoogleEarthStartup.js" id="Test"></script>
```

with content like

```
google.load("earth", "1");
google.load("maps", "2.xx");
```

It seems to want to stay in the main page with the script tags.

Is there anyway I can get around this problem?

My main reason for asking is I am using a package that overides my main html everytime I save the project.

The package allows me to add scripts via a link as seen above, although it does not make a difference with the outcome.

I get an error saying  **TypeError: google.earth is undefined**

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably simply the order of your script elements.

The scripts are executed in the order they are in the document so your error is because something in `app.js` or `Ext.ux.GEarthPanel-1.3.js` is referencing `google.earth` *before* the file `GoogleEarthStartup.js` has been executed - hence `google.earth is undefined` because `google.load("earth", "1");` has not yet been called.

Try fix try simply reordering the script elements like so...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi" id="GoogleEarth"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/GoogleEarthStartup.js" id="Test"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/googleearth/Ext.ux.GEarthPanel-1.3.js" id="GoogleEarth"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```